# How do i change an element based on cookie value set in jQuery without reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, dynamic

Ok so i am really basic with jQuery and the code i've written is no doubt inefficient but it works to a point.

I have a form where a customer selects either "Business" or "Personal" and on submission a cookie is set... I want to trigger images to change if the user has selected "Business" however for the changes to take effect the page needs reloading. How do i trigger this on selection of the option?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#thankyoumessage").css("display","none");
            
    $(".storagetype").click(function(){
        if ($('input[name=customertype]:checked').val() == "Personal" ) {
            $("#thankyoumessage").slideDown("fast"); //Slide Down Effect
            $.cookie('customerIs', 'personal_cust', { path: '/', domain: 'storebox.co.uk'});   
if ("ga" in window) {
    tracker = ga.getAll()[0];
    if (tracker)
        tracker.send("event", "customer_type", "Personal");
};         
        } else if ($('input[name=customertype]:checked').val() == "Business" ) {
            $("#thankyoumessage").slideDown("fast"); //Slide Down Effect
            $.cookie('customerIs', 'business_cust', { path: '/', domain: 'storebox.co.uk'});   
if ("ga" in window) {
    tracker = ga.getAll()[0];
    if (tracker)
        tracker.send("event", "customer_type", "Business");
};          
        } else {
            $("#thankyoumessage").slideUp("fast");  //Slide Up Effect
        }
     });  
     
      var customerIs = $.cookie('customerIs');  
     
      if (customerIs == 'personal_cust' || customerIs == 'business_cust') {  
        
        $("#customerTypeForm").css("display","none"); 
        

      };
        
        var customerIs = $.cookie('customerIs');
if (customerIs == 'business_cust') {  
        
        $('li.unit:nth-of-type(1) .unit__img-wrap img').attr('src', 'https://www.storebox.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/unit-small-trade.png');
        $('li.unit:nth-of-type(2) .unit__img-wrap img').attr('src', 'https://www.storebox.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/unit-medium-trade.png');
        $('li.unit:nth-of-type(3) .unit__img-wrap img').attr('src', 'https://www.storebox.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/unit-large-trade.png');
        

      };
          
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can copy paste the "src" changes that you have at the end of your code inside " else if ($('input[name=customertype]:checked').val() == "Business" ) "

Comment: Thanks Costa, the only issue with that is it will swap the images on selection of the options however it needs to be triggered from the customerIs == 'business_cust' value so the image switch persists on similar pages or if they revisit that page

Comment: Didn't you say you made it work on next refresh? That means keep both parts, and once you are on the page for the first time it changes it with the first part and on all the following times it will be changed based on cookie. Hmm, am I wrong?

Comment: Doh.... you're right haha, thank you buddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering what I have in comments so you can mark question as resolved ;)

> You can copy paste the "src" changes that you have at the end of your
> code inside " else if ($('input[name=customertype]:checked').val() ==
> "Business" ) "
>
> Keep both parts, and once you are on the page for the first time it
> changes it with the first part and on all the following times it will
> be changed based on the cookie.